# Reflection: casting reflected type to generic with type as string and iterating over it

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have scoured around StackOverflow and found multiple related questions, but none that answers it 'completely'. I might be wrong in my understanding, but wanted to check it -

I have a class

```
public class Foo
{
     public List<Bar> Bars = new List<Bar>();
}

public class Bar
{
}
```

Due to some reflection craziness happening, this List is getting passed only as an object -

```
Foo f = new Foo();
object o = f;
CheckItem(o, "Bars");

// CheckItem has no clue about Bar class and is thus passed the 'Bars' Field name 
public void CheckItem(Object obj, string fieldName)
{
    var value = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(obj); // returns f.Bars into value as object

    foreach (var bar in value.Bars) // won't compile as value is type object
}
```

so, I use MakeGenericType and Activator.CreateInstance magic

```
var genericClass = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] {value.GetType().FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0]}); // makes a generic of type List<Bar>
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(genericClass); // o is again of type object
foreach (var bar in o.Bars) // will fail again
```

SO - How do I call the foreach loop to iterate over the members. Every example I have seen around MakeGenericType ends at just creating the object o, none talks about how to access its members, esp in a foreach loop like above.

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `CreateInstance` at all - you don't want to create a *new* instance, right? You just want to iterate over the *existing* one.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I just need to iterate over the new instance. I used CreateInstance as a last resort and just to mention I tried that approach also, although i understand its not required.

Comment: You should be able to cast to `IEnumerable` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) and iterate over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to know about the element type, all you need to do is cast to `IEnumerable`:

```
var sequence = (IEnumerable) value;
foreach (var item in sequence)
{
    // The type of the item variable is just object,
    // but each value will be a reference to a Bar
}
```

(I'd strongly recommend using private fields and exposing properties instead, by the way - but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Bugger! Didn't realize I could cast to IEnumeratble only! Doh. Thanks!

Comment: `GetValue` returns `object` you need to cast it to something such as `IEnumerable`. Just remember that the cast may throw an exception, so be ready for that possibility.